# Setting the delegate from third to first viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I have three `viewControllers`. When I'm on the third view controller I want to send a message to the first one. I'm using a `protocol` and trying to set the `delegate` for this.

**viewControllerC.h**

```
@protocol ViewControllerCDelegate

- (void)performAction;

@end

...
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<ViewControllerCDelegate> delegate;
```

**viewControllerA.h**

```
@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController <ViewControllerCDelegate>
```

**viewControllerA.m**

```
...
- (void)performAction {
    NSLog(@"Action was performed");
}
```

So the only problem is, I can't set the `delegate` from the third to the first. How can I set `viewControllerC's` delegate to `viewControlerA`?

Here's an image to describe it:

[image]

Comment: Edited for the person that voted to close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to pass along the A controller through to the B controller to be set as the delegate for C when it is created. Kind of messy.

In this case though it might make more sense to use a notification model where Controller A listens for a NSNotification that the action was completed on C.

Comment: Brandon is correct on both accounts, if you wish to use the delegate pattern to notify ViewControllerA of an action that occurs in ViewControllerB, then you will need to "chain" delegates from A to B to C.  UINotificationCenter will work, and is much easier to implement.

Comment: This is also my own rule: use NSNotifications for broadcast messages/data and for more than 2-step delegates

Comment: Where would I put `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotficationName`?

Comment: I would suggest reading up on how notifications work at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043-SW1